# \newcommand for tabular entries using keyval

Tags: tables, macros, errors, key-value

I am trying to define a command for tabular entries using `keyval`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{a}[\dots]{#1 & }
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{b}[\dots]{#1   }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\tabularEntry}[1]{\setkeys{tabularEntryKeys}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}\hline
  \tabularEntry{a=1,b=2} % shall be "1 & 2"
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However it does not compile. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one more approach. It does neither global definitions nor use of `e-TeX` extensions and `\edef`.

> [image: tabularkeys]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}
\def\TAB{&}

\makeatletter
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{a}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowA{#1}}
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{b}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowB{#1}}
% initialize
\def\tek@rowA{}
\def\tek@rowB{}

\newcommand{\tabularEntry}[1]{\setkeys{tabularEntryKeys}{#1}%
                              \tek@rowA \expandafter\TAB\tek@rowB }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
  \tabularEntry{a=1,b=2} \\
  \tabularEntry{a=1} \\
  \tabularEntry{b=2} \\
  \tabularEntry{a,b} \\
  \tabularEntry{a} \\
  \tabularEntry{b} \\
  \tabularEntry{} \\
\end{tabular}
% \begin{tabular}{c|c}\hline
%   \tabularEntry{a=1,b=2}\\
%   \tabularEntry{a=3,b=7}\\
%   \tabularEntry{a=10,b=20}
% \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In case of more cells in one row, one needs a variant to avoid many many `\expandafter`'s: (notice the extra spaces added before  `#1` and in the initial defaults values except for `\tek@rowA` and `\tekrowD`)

```
\usepackage{keyval}
\def\TAB{&}
\makeatletter
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{a}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowA{#1}}
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{b}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowB{ #1}}
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{c}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowC{ #1}}
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{d}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowD{#1}}
% initialize
\def\tek@rowA{}
\def\tek@rowB{ }
\def\tek@rowC{ }
\def\tek@rowD{}

\newcommand{\tabularEntry}[1]{\setkeys{tabularEntryKeys}{#1}%
     \tek@rowA \expandafter\TAB
     \romannumeral0\expandafter\tek@rowB\expandafter\TAB
     \romannumeral0\expandafter\tek@rowC\expandafter\TAB
     \tek@rowD 
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: If you use something like ``-`Q`` instead of `0` you won't need the extra spaces.

Comment: @egreg no sorry, this  wouldn't work: first I would still need to leave the spaces in the initial default values; second `b=\empty` would create an error. In both cases the cause of the error is premature expansion of `\TAB`.

Comment: @egreg but thanks for the input. I do use ``\romannumeral-`0`` at some places in xint, for example in things ``\romannumeral-`0#1\relax``.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}    

\makeatletter
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{a}[\dots]{\gdef\A{#1}}
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{b}[\dots]{\gdef\B{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\tabularEntry[1]{\setkeys{tabularEntryKeys}{#1} \A & \B}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}\hline
    \tabularEntry{a=1,b=2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: moreover `\tabularEntry {b=2,a=1}` will also work in this approach, whereas the OP's code could not, even if the   scope closing nature of `&` in a tabular was avoided.

Comment: Sorry, no, but this is wrong under many respects. For instance, if you specify a new row as `\tabularEntry{b=3}`, the previous value given to `a` will appear.

Comment: @egreg, in this case it's not a bug, it's a feature. `a` is repeating several times.

Comment: @sergej This doesn't appear in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your `\setkeys` command can't straddle two cells. On the other hand globally defining `\A` and `\B` doesn't seem a good idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval,etoolbox}    

\makeatletter
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{a}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowA{\unexpanded{#1}}}
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{b}[\dots]{\def\tek@rowB{\unexpanded{#1}}}
% initialize
\def\tek@rowA{}
\def\tek@rowB{}
\newcommand\tabularEntry[1]{%
  \setkeys{tabularEntryKeys}{#1}%
  \edef\tek@row{\tek@rowA & \tek@rowB}\tek@row
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
  \tabularEntry{a=1,b=2} \\
  \tabularEntry{a=1} \\
  \tabularEntry{b=2} \\
  \tabularEntry{a,b} \\
  \tabularEntry{a} \\
  \tabularEntry{b} \\
  \tabularEntry{} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that the optional argument in `\define@key` is the value assigned to the key when the key is specified without `=<value>` following, not an initial value.

[image]

If you want the values to repeat if a key is not specified, then say

```
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{a}[\dots]{\gdef\tek@rowA{\unexpanded{#1}}}
\define@key{tabularEntryKeys}{b}[\dots]{\gdef\tek@rowB{\unexpanded{#1}}}
```

but don't use “easy” macro names such as `\A` or `\B`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy task using the `expkv-cs` package as it is fully expandable (so doesn't care for the implicit group added at `&` as it doesn't need any definitions which could be limited by that scope) and can split a key=value argument into several numbered parameters.

One can define a new splitting macro with

```
\ekvcSplit\tabularEntry{a=,b=}{#1&#2}
```

This will define the macro with two keys, both being empty arguments if they aren't used. To get `\dots` if one uses the key without a value we have to define those defaults with

```
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\tabularEntry{default a = \dots, default b = \dots}
```

The complete code would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcSplit\tabularEntry{a=,b=}{#1&#2}
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\tabularEntry{default a=\dots, default b=\dots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}\hline
  \tabularEntry{a=1,b=2} \\
  \tabularEntry{a=1} \\
  \tabularEntry{b=2} \\
  \tabularEntry{a,b} \\
  \tabularEntry{a} \\
  \tabularEntry{b} \\
  \tabularEntry{} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the results:

[image]